# Use newer hibernate or JPA 2.2 for Java 8 Date/Time in SPRING-BOOT?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jpa-2.2

Using s`pring-boot 1.5.10` (so the current) to use the Java8 Date/Time is **NOT supported** as it looks like by default this version of Spring Boot uses `Hibernate 5.0.12.Final`.
To achieve this (**Spring Boot 1.5.10**) in the `pom.xml` `properties` section overriding the version works.

```
<hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.version>
```

**Question:** **What is the best way to enable Java8 Date/Time to override hibernate version or somehow (if so then how?) use the JPA 2.2 for SPRING_BOOT?**

EDIT
With hibernate `5.0.x` I keep getting:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException:
>   Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL
>   [file:./src/main/resources/db/h2/data-h2.sql]: INSERT INTO
>   reservations (ID, RESERVATION_NAME, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) VALUES (1,
>   'res1', ParseDateTime('01 01 2001', 'd M yyyy'), ParseDateTime('02 01
>   2001', 'd M yyyy')), (2, 'res1', ParseDateTime('01 02 2001', 'd M
>   yyyy'), ParseDateTime('02 02 2001', 'd M yyyy')), (3, 'res3',
>   ParseDateTime('01 03 2001', 'd M yyyy'), ParseDateTime('02 03 2001',
>   'd M yyyy')), (4, 'res4', ParseDateTime('01 04 2001', 'd M yyyy'),
>   ParseDateTime('02 04 2001', 'd M yyyy')), (5, 'res5',
>   ParseDateTime('01 05 2001', 'd M yyyy'), ParseDateTime('02 05 2001',
>   'd M yyyy')); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:
>   Heksadecymalny string z nieparzystą liczbą znaków: "2001-01-01
>   00:00:00.0" Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters:
>   "2001-01-01 00:00:00.0"; SQL statement: INSERT INTO reservations (ID,
>   RESERVATION_NAME, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) VALUES (1, 'res1',
>   ParseDateTime('01 01 2001', 'd M yyyy'), ParseDateTime('02 01 2001',
>   'd M yyyy')),

but when using the `5.2.12.Final` everything is working .

Answer (score 7):

Hibernate 5.x already had support for the Java 8 Date/Time API, but within a separate artifact called `hibernate-java8`.

Using Maven, you can include it like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

However, since Hibernate 5.2.x, the baseline Java version for Hibernate is Java 8, so there was no longer a need to keep a separate module for the Java 8 date/time support. That's why it was now merged into `hibernate-core`, as documented in the [migration guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Migration-Guide---5.2):

> Hibernate 5.2 is built using Java 8 JDK and will require Java 8 JRE at runtime (we are investigating whether Java 9 will also work). This has a number of implications:
>
> - The hibernate-java8 module has been merged into hibernate-core and the Java 8 date/time types are now natively supported.

So, to answer your question, for Hibernate 5.0.x and Hibernate 5.1.x, the official way to support the new date/time API is to use the `hibernate-java8` module.

Comment: But `spring-boot` already has this dependency. So questeion is not about version but what is the most `spring-boot`ish way to provide the functionality of hibernate 5.1.x. Btw `Hibernate 5.0.x` is not working with Java 8 Date/Time.

Comment: When I use `5.0.x` I keep getting error as in my EDIT of question. It works however when changed to `5.2.12`

Comment: @mCs If you use Spring data, the best way to update from a specific version is to update the entire Spring data releasetrain. This can be done by configuring the `spring-data-releasetrain.version` Maven property, for example `<spring-data-releasetrain.version>Kay-SR4</spring-data-releasetrain.version>`. This guarantees that you use a compatible Spring Data version with a given Hibernate version. However, it also means that you can't use the newest of the newest version in that case.

Answer (score 1):

One of the features added with Hibernate 5 is the support of Java 8 classes like the Date and Time API, so you can add the `.jar` to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and playing around with *spring-boot-parent* (finally opted using latest 1.5.x version: 1.5.16.RELEASE) and *spring-boot-starter-data-jpa* versions didn't help.

What did help in the end, was adding the dependency on `hibernate-java8`, with a **5.1.X** version. As OP indicates correctly, spring boot by default already brings this dependency, but with a lower (==hibernate.version) version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>
```